# Update type of a column in liquibase

Tags: liquibase, changeset

I want to update the type of a column named "password". At the moment it has type NVARCHAR(40) and I want it to be of type NVARCHAR(64). This is what I did:

```xml
<changeSet id="1 - change password length" author="chris311">
    <update tableName="tablename">
        <column name="password" type="NVARCHAR(64)"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

What else is there to do? Because this obviously does not change anything in the DB.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're using the wrong refactoring operation. Try [modifyDataType](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html)

Answer (score 40):

```
<changeSet id="increase-password-length" author="martin">
  <modifyDataType tableName="tablename" columnName="password" newDataType="NVARCHAR(64)"/>
</changeSet>
```

You can check out http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html for more documentation

Comment: Ehhhhrm thanks but, exactly the same was already said in the answer before!?

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do by using sql tag:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-sql" id="example-sql" context="migrate">
    <sql dbms="mysql">
      ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN password NVARCHAR(64)
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;

**For MySQL:**
Use [addNotNullConstraint](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-not-null-constraint.html?Highlight=addNotNullConstraint)

Explanation:

On MySQL, the pitfall is that [modifyDataType](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/modify-data-type.html?Highlight=modifyDatatype) is going to change the null constraint to nullable (the default).
Liquibase is going to warn you about this and not doing the change.
It will even give you a hint to do it by using SQL.

Using the addNotNullConstraint, in MySQL you need to give the datatype too, so you can keep your constraint and change the type.